# mapping <C-x><C-s> to save file in commandline mode

Tags: neovim, init.vim

I have a peculiar situation where the value of a number on the nvim screen on which the cursor is sitting gets decremented by 1 when I (often accidentally) hit `<C-x><C-s>` in commandline mode (I moved a few months ago after over 25 years with `emacs`. So, I was wanting to map my `<C-x><C-s>` to save the file in commandline mode.

I tried adding:

```
cnoremap <C-x><C-s> :w<cr>
```

to map my `<C-x><C-s>` to save the file, and put this line in my `.config/nvim/init.vim` but it does not seem to be making any difference in the behavior of the key combination.

What am I doing wrong. At this point, I would be fine disabling `<C-x><C-s>` altogether as a last resort.

Comment: What's console mode? `cnoremap` works in command-line mode. Did you mean to use `:nnoremap` instead?

Comment: OK, command line mode, will edit.

Comment: I don't see how this mapping would make sense in command-line mode. Is the root cause maybe confusion of Vim's modes? See `:help vim-modes` or Vivian's answer.

Comment: There are some (largely historical, I believe) references to « command mode », which we now usually call Normal mode.

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: Yes, of course, I wanted to try it out first before accepting it. Thanks very much for the answer! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One risk with the mapping:

```
cnoremap <C-x><C-s> :w<cr>
```

is that that it assume that the command line is empty.
If your command line is not empty it will merge the two.

E.g. if the command line contains `:b` it will run `:b:w<CR>`.

To avoid that confusion it is usually recommended to clear the command line first:

```
cnoremap <C-x><C-s> <c-u>w<cr>
```

Or in modern Vim:

```
cnoremap <C-x><C-s> <cmd>w<cr>
```

That being said the proposition of @Friedrich to do:

```
nnoremap <C-x><C-s> <cmd>w<cr>
```

will probably bring you closer to the Emacs experience.

From what you wrote ("the value of a number get decremented") make me believe that you actually hit <kbd>Ctrl x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl s</kbd> in normal mode. Indeed <kbd>Ctrl x</kbd> decrement the next integer on the line in normal mode.

And <kbd>Ctrl a</kbd> increases the next integer on the line (that I also found by accident).